# Deletion in queue from front in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, queue

I have written a program for implementaion of queue using Python. Insertion and display of the queue works fine. But I can't delete element from front of queue. I have tried `del` keyword as well as `pop` method. In both the ways, the element is deleted from fron of the queue, insted it deleted from front+1. For example, the queue is [15, 25, 78, 93, 41, 589]. If I chose to delete element from fron, the element 15 is deleted. But if I again chose to delete element from front, the element 78 is deleted insted of 25.
Following is the function of deleteion operation from front:

```
def dequeue():
    global front, rear, queue
    if (is_queue_empty()):
        print("\nQueue is empty.")
    else:
        item = queue[front]
        queue.pop(front)
        if (front == rear):
            front = -1
            rear = -1
        else:
            front = front + 1
        print("\nDeleted element is ", item)
```

Follwing is my original program:

```
def is_queue_empty():
    if (front == -1):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


def is_queue_full():
    if (rear == maxsize - 1):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


def enqueue():
    global front, rear, queue, item
    if (is_queue_full()):
        print("\nQueue is full.")
    else:
        item = int(
            input("\nEnter the item at position " + str(rear + 1) + ": "))
        if (front == -1):
            front = 0
            rear = 0
        else:
            rear = rear + 1
        queue.append(item)


def dequeue():
    global front, rear, queue
    if (is_queue_empty()):
        print("\nQueue is empty.")
    else:
        item = queue[front]
        queue.pop(front)
        if (front == rear):
            front = -1
            rear = -1
        else:
            front = front + 1
        print("\nDeleted element is ", item)


# print the list
def display():
    print("\nQueue Size = ", maxsize, ", Number Of Elements In The Queue = ",
          (rear - front) + 1, ", Occupied Space In The Queue = ", rear + 1,
          ", Available Size In The Queue = ", maxsize - (rear + 1))
    if (is_queue_empty()):
        print("\nQueue is empty.")
    else:
        print("\nYour queue: ", queue)


def set_queue_size():
    global maxsize
    maxsize = int(input("Enter the size of the queue: "))


queue = []  # Initializing an empty queue
front = rear = -1

# Driver Code
set_queue_size()

print("\n1. EnQueue")
print("\n2. DeQueue")
print("\n3. Display")
print("\n4. Update the size of the queue")
print("\n5. Exit")

while (1):
    ch = int(input("\nEnter your choice: "))

    if (ch == 1):
        enqueue()
        continue
    elif (ch == 2):
        dequeue()
        continue
    elif (ch == 3):
        display()
        continue
    elif (ch == 4):
        set_queue_size()
        continue
    elif (ch == 5):
        break
    else:
        print("\nWrong choice. Try again")
        continue
```

NOTE: I am trying to write the program without importing any Python library

Comment: You don't need the values `front` and `rear` at all. `is_queue_empty` should return `len(queue) == 0`; `is_queue_full` should return `len(queue) == maxsize`. If you want to display 1-based indexes, the position of the first entry is always `1` and the last is always `len(queue)`. All the other calculations can be made using `len(queue)` (i.e. the number of items currently in the queue) and `maxsize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at below. You don't need `front` index. When you `popped` `front` item. it will remove that item completely from queue. That is why you don't need it. But in your code you every `dequeue` increased front.

But python will automatically removes it from queue.

`front=0` always. So just use `queue.pop(0)`.

Look at below.

```
def is_queue_empty():
    if (rear == 0):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


def is_queue_full():
    if (rear == maxsize):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


def enqueue():
    global rear, queue, item
    if (is_queue_full()):
        print("\nQueue is full.")
    else:
        item = int(
            input("\nEnter the item at position " + str(rear) + ": "))
        rear = rear + 1
        queue.append(item)


def dequeue():
    global rear, queue
    if (is_queue_empty()):
        print("\nQueue is empty.")
    else:
        item = queue[0]
        queue.pop(0)
        rear = rear - 1
        print("\nDeleted element is ", item)


# print the list
def display():
    print("\nQueue Size = ", maxsize, ", Number Of Elements In The Queue = ",
        (rear) + 1, ", Occupied Space In The Queue = ", rear,
        ", Available Size In The Queue = ", maxsize - rear)
    if (is_queue_empty()):
        print("\nQueue is empty.")
    else:
        print("\nYour queue: ", queue)


def set_queue_size():
    global maxsize
    maxsize = int(input("Enter the size of the queue: "))


queue = []  # Initializing an empty queue
rear = 0

# Driver Code
set_queue_size()

print("\n1. EnQueue")
print("\n2. DeQueue")
print("\n3. Display")
print("\n4. Update the size of the queue")
print("\n5. Exit")

while (1):
    ch = int(input("\nEnter your choice: "))

    if (ch == 1):
        enqueue()
        continue
    elif (ch == 2):
        dequeue()
        continue
    elif (ch == 3):
        display()
        continue
    elif (ch == 4):
        set_queue_size()
        continue
    elif (ch == 5):
        break
    else:
        print("\nWrong choice. Try again")
        continue
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it gives the correct output